# ELK Heartbeat dashbaord add ID

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

How can I add ID field to Kibana / Uptime dashboard?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed ver 7.3. This shows "NAME" as one of the column headers. You can specify what is displayed in there in monitor configuration:

```
- type: http
  name: 'QA.Service - THIS HERE'
  enabled: true
  schedule: '@every 5m'
  urls: ["http://checkstatus/blah/blah"]
  check.response: 
    status: 200
    json:
      - description: Json Response
        condition:
          equals:
            Status: Ok
```